# how does Flex relate (work with) Apache web server?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm new to Flex. Could someone help me understand how Flex generally works with HTTP, HTML, SWF, and Apache web server? Does Flex code sit on the server or on the client?  Also, how does communicating with the client using AMF change anything (does this bypass Apache web server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the case here exactly, but you just offer your compiled Flex application from your web server. Type the URI to that in your browser and it will launch the flash player to run it.

Answer (score 0):

AMF is just a format, everything goes 'through' the server since it is the one listening on the port :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a wealth of information regarding Flex out on the web.  I suggest searching and catching up on some of that documentation, but in short:  Flex is an XML-based language that can be combined with ActionScript to produce Flash SWF's that run inside the Flash Player virtual machine either via a plug-in in the browser, an AIR application on the desktop, or a native iOS or AIR-driven Android mobile application.  It is only used for client-side applications, but can communicate with server-side code (Java, PHP, ColdFusion, etc) using the AMF compact binary protocol.  The SWF can be served up using Apache or any other web-server technology.